# Locus of Complex number Collapsing into a single point.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-geometry, locus

Suppose we have the Locus $$|z-1|=1$$ obviously it is supposed to represent a circle of radius 1 and centered at $(1,0)$. But now if i expand it I get , 
$$z^{2}+1+2zcos\theta =1$$
which eventually gives us $$|z|(|z|-2cos\theta )=0$$.
But we know $Arg(z)$ is nothing bus $2cos\frac{\theta }{2}$ by taking $$z-1=e^{i \theta }$$ which simplifies to $$z = 2cos\frac{\theta }{2}e^{i\frac{\theta }{2}}$$
Now from this we get $\theta$ must be $0,2\pi...$. Which  only represents the points of z on real axis and not the other points. Why does this happen?

Comment: On a circle you've infinite amount of point so when $\theta$ is describing$ [0,2\pi[$, z obviously go on complex axis, let's take $\theta=\pi$

Comment: How do you go from $\lvert z-1\rvert1$ to $z^2+1+2z\cos\theta=1$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I use the expansion of modulus as $|z1+z2|^2=|z1|^2+|z2|^2+2|z1||z2|cost$ where t is the angle between the two complexes.

Comment: So, the $z$ from $\lvert z-1\rvert=1$ is **not** the $z$ from $z^2+1+2z\cos\theta=1$, right?! Besides that, we were all supposed to guess what $\theta$ was, right?!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos no both the $z$ were same , yes I guessed $/theta$ but we should have given such values of $/theta$ which represent otherpoints on the circle too.